# How to uniquely identify userId obtained from android Facebook login on backend server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, devise, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

We are developing an Android application and are implementing Facebook Login using Firebase. On our backend server, every new user is identified by a unique email. In Facebook, we encountered a situation where, when a user logs in using Facebook, we get a unique Uid but getting an email is not necessary. I can verify the user on my backed server but I am not able to understand how should I use this Uid to identify a unique user on our server. I don't have an email. Is there any particular methodology for this or am I missing something?

Kindly suggest a suitable way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you may want to have `facebook_id` field in your `User` model having `uid` stored. Than you might want to add uniqueness validation on this field (and unique index as well), so you don't have more than one user with the same facebook uid in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought of the same apporach but I was wondering how this uid is useful to me later? I mean what is the use of it?

Comment: Can't answer to this question though.. I suppose, you can't obtain user's data only by its UUID. So it's for identifying user only, imo.